# Connecting to mongodb using ObjCMongodb with meteor

Tags: meteor, objcmongodb

I have a meteor server running on my localhost port 3000. I want to connect to its mongodb using an objective C app. So far I have been unable to connect, but I believe that I have installed ObjCMongodb correctly into my project following the steps listed in the [README](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/wiki/GettingStarted).  I use the ObjCMongodb line of code to connect `MongoConnection *dbConn = [MongoConnection connectionForServer:@"127.0.0.1:3000" error:&error];` where 3000 is the port where the meteor application is running. One of my mongodb collection's is called 'messages' so I use `MongoDBCollection *collection = [dbConn collectionWithName:@"messages"];` I try to do various commands as stated in the README, however none of them work. I know it must be the connection to the server that is making it fail or improper installation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Mongodb runs on 2+ your meteor web port. So that would be 3002

Comment: awesome thanks. Now when I try to define and update a collection the collection would be @"mydb.messages"?. When I use the mongodb shell and say `show collections` messages is one of the listed collections. Thus using the `collectionWithName:@"mydb.messages"` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: In the shell, what does `db` or `db.getName()` give you?

Comment: @nate i think it should just be 'messages'

Comment: db or db.getName() both return meteor. So it is 'meteor.messages'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access my meteor mondgodb database I used the ObjCMongodb package [here](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB). The following code was then used as stated in the ReadMe to connect to the meteor app running on the localhost.

```
MongoConnection *dbConn = [MongoConnection connectionForServer:@"127.0.0.1:3002" error:&error];
MongoDBCollection *collection = [dbConn collectionWithName:@"meteor.messages"];
```

Where the port was 3000, but the mondgodb was +2 making it port 3002. The collectionWithName was then `meteor.(my collection wanting to be accessed)`. 
Special thanks to noa and Akshat.